# Why is array order changed?

Tags: python, arrays

I am confused by following result in python. The order of the array is changed. How is this valid? I used Spyder IDE to run the code.

```
arr = {'1','2','3'}
print(arr)
arr.pop()
print(arr)
arr.remove('1')
print(arr)

>>
{'2', '3', '1'}
{'3', '1'}
{'3'}
```

Comment: You have a set not a list (array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as `array` in python.
What you declare in the line `arr = {'1','2','3'}` is a `set`, a data structure that doesn't (necessarily) keep the order of the elements.

Please read more about `set` and python data structures in general: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: "There is no such thing as `array` in python" isn't quite correct. There is [`array`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/array.html) in Pythons standard library. The problem is that a lot of new Python programmers call a list an array and that leads to confusion.